# Breaking a Neder or Shavu'a

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

What if someone make a Neder or a Shavu'a in the name of Hashem, and intentionally broke it?

What would someone's punishment be for that? Kares, Malkus etc.?

How can someone do Teshuva for something like that?